# Accessing Xubuntu GUI remotely on linode

Tags: command-line, ssh, xubuntu

I'm ssh'd as root into my linode server and have installed Xubuntu (for Ubuntu 10.04). Now I'd like to use it, but issuing starts brings about the fatal error no screens found. I've installed and run emacs which appears as a GUI interface with the Terminal (I'm using OS X) window, so how can I do the same with Xubuntu so I can see a desktop?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can install X2go. It is a terminal server that will give you either the entire desktop, or a single application run on the server. You can install it from their PPA, which you can find on https://launchpad.net/~x2go/+archive/stable

You'll then install x2goserver and x2goclient, pyhoca-gui or pyhoca-cli. These are clients.

Comment: I tried to get x2go client installed but I get this error:

Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  x2goclient: Depends: libssh-4 (>= 0.4.7) but it is not going to be installed
E: Broken packages